# Is there any way to get code from a running python file that is deleted?

Tags: python

I have an extreme problem. I use replit as my IDE AND I accidently deleted my python script. It is serving a flask app that has launched 3 child processes. Can I get the code of the file while it's still running? I have no backups. I have written a lot of code that I don't want to lose. I am using ubuntu.

I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: You could use a file recovery software to get the deleted file back.

Comment: Searching around the Internet you might come across this [gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/simonw/8aa492e59265c1a021f5c5618f9e6b12).

Comment: @metatoaster that should be an answer.

Comment: I can't see why there are votes to close. The two votes are: an unspecified specific reason; a claim that there is more than one question (I see only one).

Comment: Eventually closed for a good reason (duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any type of Unix (you are), then the answer **may be** yes. (But see last paragraph.)

Files are not deleted when you remove the directory entry. They are only deleted when there are zero directory entries, and zero processes with the file open.

## So how to access it.

On Gnu/Linux systems there is a `proc` directory. This directory has a sub-directory for each process.

- Get the process ID of the desired process.
- `cd /proc/«process-id»/fd`
- `ls -l`
- play guess the file, it will be one of these (usually not many).

This will only work if Python keeps the file open. (I just tested. It works for Bash, but I can't get this to work for Python. It looks like Python closes the file.)

Comment: Indeed, the Python interpreter reads the script into memory and compiles it into an internal representation at startup. So really, in this specific case, the answer is simply no.